# MVC - if query in a model of an object graps all needed data, can child object be without model?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Consider the following part of a web-app:
A wall which contains an unknown number of blocks, which themselves contain an unknown number of boxes.

My approach (yet on paper only, sorry no code) will be to create a `class wall`, a `class block` and a `class box`. (wall contains blocks contain boxes). (each block and each box may have different param values)

In my database, I have information about the wall, about the blocks and about the boxes in separate tables. Yet, with only one large (but optimized) query I can grab all data I need. (each box has the id of its parent block). Correct me if i'm wrong, but lowering the number of queries and relying more on php stuff seems to be the right way to improve speed.

Based on that, I was wondering :
Following an MVC pattern/structure, should `block` and `box` also have a Model, even if the query in my wall Model already grabs all the needed information? Or is that just not the right way to go?

Thank you!

Comment: Model in MVC is not a class or an object. It is one of two layers.

Comment: @tereško absolutely, an my question is whether this second layer is necessary. (sorry if badly explained, english not being my language :/)

Comment: @leMoisela: Not at all. Just convert the resultset into a json string and send it to the browser.

Comment: thanks @hakre ! I'm not really used to json, but you're basically saying that I could get rid of not only the model layer but the complete block and box objects? Beyond being a solution to my problem, would this solution be considered as a good approach?

Comment: The *second layer* is "presentation layer". It contains controllers, views and templates.

Comment: @leMoisela: Sure because you only fetch the data from the database to get it into the browser as you outline in your question. So keep the server processing as lightweight as possible. Why code something when you don't need it?

Comment: @hakre thx ! I'll have a look to Json ! Btw, if, instead of directly getting my data in the browser I have some parsing and/or calculation to compute on this data, would you still advise me to make all this on the client side? (In other words, is the combination of data manipulation ease + calculation processing worth having everything on the client side to keep to server processes as low as possible?)

Comment: If you want to waste server resources, you can do the calculation on the server-side. However, it scales better to push all that into the browser.

Comment: @hakre thanks for your precious help!